# Insertion in maps in C++

Tags: c++, maps

```
map<string ,vector<string> > hashes;

hashes.insert(pair<string,vector<string> > (a,b ));  //error coming
```

What is the problem coming when i am using the above statement in C++, where a and b are strings?
How does the insertion takes place in this type (i.e. one container containing more container) of associative container?

Many many thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
hashes[a].push_back(b)
```

That's if you want b to be appended to the present vector.  If you want it to replace it, use

```
hashes[a].assign(1, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a string where a vector of string is needed. You need to insert `b` into a vector, then insert (a, your_vector) into the map.

Alternatively, use a `multimap<string, string>` to get the same basic effect in a way you may find easier to use. This would allow your `insert(pair<...>(a, b))`.

Also consider using `std::make_pair` instead of instantiating `std::pair` directly. It'll deduce the types for the arguments so you don't need to fill them out explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the definition:

```
vector<string> v;
v.push_back("mystring");

hashes.insert(std::make_pair("key", v));
```

Note how the second parameter to `make_pair` is a `vector<string>`. This will never fail then. It will fail if the second parameter is a string.